# Is there a single documented case of severe COVID-19 in a patient having fully recovered from COVID-19?

Tags: covid-19

Is there a single documented case of severe COVID-19 (reinfection) in a patient having fully recovered from COVID-19?

For the purposes of this question, I'm excluding people with an immune disease, such as HIV. Further, [extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagan_standard), so both COVID-19 cases should have  positive antibody and PCR tests.

Comment: The only acceptable answer to this question will be "yes" which makes it kind of a strawman question.

Comment: @CareyGregory You all buried [my answer](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/a/25720/10901) that relied on the rarity of (severe) COVID-19 reinfections. There were probably ~5M severe COVID-19 cases in the US alone (based on 0.5M deaths). If you disagree so much with my answer, you should be able to find **one** thoroughly documented **re**infection.

Comment: I don't really have a strong opinion on your answer and didn't downvote it, so I didn't bury anything. My comment above is just to point out a problem with this question that I think you can improve. Nobody can prove a negative, so this question will never have an acceptable answer until such a case is found. That doesn't seem like a very useful question.

Comment: @CareyGregory You are the only one who criticized my answer, and your criticism was totally unfair too, seeing as you are concerned about being unable to find a **single** severe COVID-19 reinfection.

Comment: I'm sorry you feel offended but your answer has 3 downvotes, none of which are mine. What you see as criticism was me trying to keep your answer from being deleted. I'm not concerned about whether there's a single case or not.

Comment: I don't understand why this is a question. I know loads of people who have had covid twice. Right now one of my friends is severely ill with it for the second time and we are all worried about him. If you want records I can put you in touch.

Comment: @CareyGregory *"What you see as criticism was me trying to keep your answer from being deleted."* Why would it be deleted and by whom?

Comment: As you refer to a saying, what kind of general paradigm or issue are you holding Covid as one example for? If any pathogen can be qualified as such, and such more or less, without relating to the defensive strength of the host? if there were only strong patients CoV would still be considered dangerous? Something like that? - I could refer to a patient being reported recovered from severe disease without B-cells/antibodies. That would be beyond your question.